# Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal: image not resizing vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Twitter Bootstrap 3 and I'm using a modal dialog to display 2 divs side by side. The left div contains a centered image which should adjust to its container dimensions, keeping the aspect ratio.
My issue is the following: if I resize the browser window vertically the image height doesn't decrease bellow a certain value and eventually gets outside the dialog boundaries, resulting in something like this [image]

This is the code I've reached so far:

```
 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 90%; height: 100%;">
      <div class="modal-content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: red;">
        <div class="modal-body" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <div class="text-center " style="float: left; width: 60%; background-color: #f1f1f1; height: 100%; display: table;">
                <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; ">
                    <img class=""src="img/project_image.png" width="100%" style="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="float: right; width: 40%; background-color: blue;">
                <p>Big Rabbit Illustration</p>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Could you put it in a jsfiddle, so that we can experiment with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. Your image doesnt have a height, it only has a width.

`<img class=""src="img/project_image.png" width="100%" style="" />`

but the real problem starts here. If you put height at 100% the image might look distorted.
So you might want to write a JQuery for the image. Something like, when the window height is this big, the image use `height="100%"` and when the window width is this big use `width="100%"`